# Bash - Increment a variable until it can be found in another variable + if it matches a condition

Tags: bash

I need to increment over the results that this variable will bring, one by one, sequentially:

```
a= "a b c d x y z"
```

until it can be matched in another variable

```
b="gibberish x gibberish y"
```

When that happens, declare the very first match as a variable

```
var=x
```

And then out of this resulting variable, test for a condition

```
if test $var = $(something); then //it's good//; else //keep incrementing//; fi
```

If the condition is not met, keep incrementing the original variable until that condition matched

```
var=y
```

So on and so forth until everything matches up

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Are you getting any errors? What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Closest answer to what i need is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308985 but i found the declaration of the arrays too complicated for my knowledge in bash. It's like this, but i need to introduce this third condition, and only a single variable to come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to do with bash and loops, looping over each of the characters in `a` while looping over the words in `b` you check if the current character matches the word (since you don't want to match characters that are randomly included within a word in `b`)

If that match is found, you then check against `something` and if the character that matched equals whatever is in `something` you are done. Otherwise, you simply continue looping. You can use a flag (e.g. true/false, 1/0) variable to indicate if a successful match was found that agreed with `something` before the end of both variables `a` and `b` were reached.

You can do that similar to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

a="a b c d x y z"
b="gibberish x gibberish y"

found=0     ## flag indicating var= successfully assigned
var=""

something="${1:-x}"     ## quick hack on your something

for i in $a; do                                 ## loop over chars in a
    for j in $b; do                             ## loop over words in b
        if [ "$i" = "$j" ]; then                ## if char is word
            if [ "$i" = "$something" ]; then    ## is char $somehthing?
                var="$i"                        ## assing to var
                found=1;                        ## set found flag
                break;                          ## break word loop
            fi
        fi
    done
    [ "$found" -eq 1 ] && break;                ## if found, exit char loop
done

if [ "$found" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "matched with '$var'"    ## output which char matched
else
    echo "no match found"
fi
```

**Example Use/Output**

Where `something` will match `x`

```
$ bash match.sh
matched with 'x'
```

Where `something` will match `y`:

```
$ bash match.sh y
matched with 'y'
```

Where no character in `a` agrees with `something`

```
$ bash match.sh foo
no match found
```

There are other ways to do this, with temporary files, `grep -f` and REGEX, but this is one way to use bash alone. Look things over and let me know if you have questions or if I missed the intent of `something`.

Comment: Thank you very much, a good detailed answer. In my case the "something" is the output of a command. How do i integrate the $(command) into the array?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you can always do `a="a b c d x y z $(something)"` or if you want it directly in the loop, `for i in $a $(something); ...` (note: `a` isn't an array, it is a simple list. An array would be `a=(a b c d x y z $(something))`). The `$(...)` is just a *commend substitution* where the output of the command is substituted in its place. You can use that anywhere you like. Always be mindful of quoting whee needed. If `$(somehting)` will contain whitespace and you want to treat it all as 1 value, you would need, e.g. `a=(a b c d x y z "$(something)")`